# jsf security realm in weblogic server

Tags: java, security, jsf, weblogic, jdbcrealm

I'm a complete newbie to JSF and WebLogic. I am using JSF 2.2 and weblogic server. I need to make user authoritation based on user role. I have two types of users: employee and admin. Employee should not enter admin page. Admin can create, update and remove users and give them role. I read weblogic documentation and found security realm. However I need to implement this security realm in JSF. Additionally, all users should be in oracle database and match with weblogic Users, Groups, And Security Roles

Comment: I found a solution for GlassFish and TomCat but not for WebLogic

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want to add vital information to your question, it is better to include it by editing the original question instead of adding it as a comment. That way, you'll make it easier for others to parse the information necessary to come up with a good answer.

Comment: JSF has no security realms. Java web applications have. Otherwise you need to use a security framework like picketlink, shiro, or similar (this is not extensive nor a recomendation. Choose one yourself)

Comment: Thank you for your advice @anothernode

Comment: Kukeltje, you mean I cannot use weblogic security realm in JSF, right? Is it possible to use a security framework working with database to check user roles and give them permission?

Comment: Is it possible to use PicketLink in JSF application and weblogic server?